# adding credit card scanning with camera

Tags: ios, swift

IOS8 has some built in features in Safari and Apple Pay to scan credit cards with video cam, so that the user would not have to manually punch in the number. 
Anyone knows is there is an API call or an out of the box Controller available for Swift that would allow to add this feature to any IOS application?

Comment: Any news on this??

Comment: Same question - any news? It seems that Apple just don't want to open their scanner for public...